# Average of two integers

Tags: python

To find average of two integers such that result is also an integer, I came across the following approaches in python:

```
int((low + high) / 2)
low + ((high - low) // 2)
(low + high) // 2
```

Question: Which approach should I prefer when all give the same (correct) result?

Comment: if low =2 and high=3, what is the "correct" result?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. I would personally prefer the third option for readability, but it doesn't really matter

Comment: not sure about python, but in languages where integer can overflow - 2nd variant is the only correct one

Comment: I think you're looking for the midpoint in an interval, not an average.

Comment: @JamesK: 2 and 3 should give out 2. I thought it was evident from the above approaches that result is the floor division.

Answer (score 2):

The `low + ((high - low) // 2)` pattern avoids overflow issues in languages with fixed-size integers. Python `int`s can get arbitrarily large, so `(low + high) // 2` is not an overflow concern in Python. Either one is fine, but I would prefer `(low + high) // 2`, because it’s simpler. (If you microbenchmarked it, I would expect it to be faster, too – fewer operations, fewer intermediate values.)

The one you should definitely *not* use is `int((low + high) / 2)`. It passes through floating point, which there’s no reason to do when integer division exists. It will start returning imprecise results for large values of `low` and `high` because `float`s have limited precision.

```
>>> low, high = 2**52, 2**52 + 3
>>> int((low + high) / 2)
4503599627370498
>>> (low + high) // 2
4503599627370497
```

Even if you never encounter values that large, don’t make readers think about it.

Comment: Can you explain how the first approach will return imprecise results for large values of `low` and `high`?

Comment: @Saad: Added an example to the answer.